# Parsing DateTime strings

Tags: c#, string, datetime, parsing

I'm having some difficulties parsing strings of DateTime using DateTime.ParseExact.

```
    DateTime result;
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    // Parse date-only value with invariant culture.
    //format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
format = "d";
    try
    {

        result = DateTime.ParseExact(data+" 12:00:00 AM", format, provider);
    }
```

data is a string variable loaded with dates of the format "5/20/2009". I tried tacking on a fake time just to see if that would work, and it didn't(with or without the tack on). I also tried using the "g" format specifier and it did not work, I always get the exception that it isn't a valid DateTime string. The only dates it works for is like "12/20/2009" (notice that 2 digits in the "MM" part)

I can not get this routine to work with single digit months! Microsofts own example from MSDN is

```
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 6/15/2009 (en-US)
```

and it will not work with this. I am just not understanding what I am doing wrong. I have also tried my own format specifiers like "mm/dd/yyyy" and "MM/dd/yyyy" but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to parse a DateTime in en-US format, you have to specify the en-US culture:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("6/15/2009", "d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Why must I specify that culture? also, that is not ParseExact. We know exactly what format the date strings are coming from, why can a format string not be used? Using this, we could bring in things that shouldn't be there(specifying time in a datefield is a no no)

Comment: I've changed my example to ParseExact. You must specify a culture because you say you want your input to be parsed in a culture specific way (namely in en-US format).

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use:

```
format = "M/dd/yyyy";
```

Notice only 1 M.

See [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier) for confirmation and further details.

Comment: No, thats wrong. That will make it so that "11/15/2009" turns to "1/15/2009"

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Because I have, and it seems to work (11/15/2009 does not become 1/15/2009). The 1 'M' simply indicates not to add a zero in front of one-digit months (much like calling ToString("0") on an Integer returns the number without any padding zeroes).

Comment: Dan's right. You don't understand what the format string means if you think it'll convert 11 -> 1 without the extra M.

Comment: hmm.. that actually does work, maybe I used "m" instead of "M" when I tested it(or maybe that was before your edit)

Answer (score 1):

ParseExact requires that you use the exact long format specifier (e.g. mM/dd/yyyy) instead of just "d"

Comment: That will still give an exception. If I tack on a "0" to make somethin like "06/20/2009" then it will parse everything correct, but the month will be 1, so it'll be "1/20/2009" and this is making no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The character '/' when used in format strings is just a placeholder for the culture-specific date separation character. If you want it to be literal you must escape it with '\'.

If I understood your problem correctly you may be able to parse your text with:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(data, "MM\/dd\/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantProvider);
```