# Parsing any date format string to datetime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

In C#, how do I parse a string of format `"dd/mm/yyyy"` or format `"dd-mm-yyyy"` to datetime?
I get an error that says my string is not in the correct format. I need to be able to parse all the formats not just one of them.

Comment: "I need to be able to parse all the formats" - given that there exist both `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` formats, any dates for the 12th or earlier in the month must be ambiguous - it's a problem unsolvable by a computer.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.

Comment: What formats are you trying to [parse exactly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/332de853.aspx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing DateTime strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325400/parsing-datetime-strings)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually, even a human can't decide if you intend the 3rd of april or the 4th of March...

Comment: @Teejay - yes, that's why "yyyy-MM-dd" should be the one and only format to ever be used by everyone. ever. Well, until the year 9999 at least...

Comment: @Corak Since I'm from Italy, I think also **dd/MM/yyyy** is actually good. Definitely, **MM/dd/yyyy** is the most non-sense and confusing one.

Comment: @Corak - RFC 2550 deals with that limitation.

Comment: @Teejay - Germany here, for us it's dd.MM.yyyy. But that also quickly becomes "wrong" when adding a time. "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"? dafuq? Therefore: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" => *logic*! ^_^

Comment: You're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326127/datetime-tryparse-all-possible-type-of-dates or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211765/parsing-any-valid-datetime-format-to-sql-server-compatible-format ?

Answer (score 15):

You can define any format you like - plus you can get a list of defaults for a given culture.

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var formats = new[] { "M-d-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "M.d.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy" }
        .Union(ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()).ToArray();

DateTime.ParseExact("07/23/2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
DateTime.ParseExact("07-23-2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
DateTime.ParseExact("23-07-2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
DateTime.ParseExact("23.07.2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
```

**Output:**

```
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 8):

`mm` means minute, uppercase `MM` means month.

Apart from that, you have to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` if you want to parse strings with `/` as  date separator since this is the replacement char for your current culture's date separator:

So this works:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23/07/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

Answer (score 5):

You need to define which date formats are you looking to accept. There's no such thing as all formats. Once you define that you can pass format array to `DateTime.ParseExact`

Your code can look like this:

```
string[] formats = new string[2] {"dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy"};

string date = "23-02-2013";
try
{
    DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
}
catch (FormatException)
{ 
    // your error handling code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method with whatever specified format.

```
    var d = DateTime.ParseExact(token, "dd-MM-yyyy", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Comment: Your format string is wrong.  `mm` is minute, not month.

Comment: @JohnKoerner thanks for catching that.